# Using function from form in Access SQL statement?

Tags: ms-access

I know if I make a code module in Access and place a function in it, I can run a query that has embedded calls to that function. However, I want to know if I can get a function that belongs to the **code part of a form** to be recognized by Access in a query. So far I cannot find a way, but it seems to me that this should be possible.

Thanks,
Cameron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can - the function has to be made **PUBLIC** and the form must be **OPEN** when you run the query.

Most of the time I put all common functions in a separate code module.

Comment: Oooh. Thanks! The reason I want to keep as much code belonging the form as possible is because everything I do will eventually have to be copy-pasted into different databases... So I'm trying to keep everything tied to a few necessary forms

Comment: Also, you have to refer to the function as a member of the form, e.g., Forms!MyForm.MyFunction().